# Setting up SQLite without copying and pasting application file to every project directory

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

I am revisiting an old bootcamp course to refresh my memory and doing things locally vs. on the Cloud9 development environment. I'm confused because I've downloaded SQLite per the downloads page [image: for Windows] and saved it to a folder under C:\sqlite. I can load the shell and run it if I save a db file in the same root as the folder I downloaded the shell to, but if I open different project directories elsewhere on my computer for different projects/exercises it doesn't work unless I copy and paste the sqlite application into the same folder and open it separately from the command prompt I'm using to control my Ruby applications.

Am I missing something, or is there no way to download sqlite as something that integrates itself into the windows command prompt without having to copy the sqlite application file into every project directory that has a db?

Comment: Seems likely that you need to add the executable to your [PATH](https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding the C:\sqlite directory to the Path variable in advanced system settings.